# How to make loading progress when sending data to the database

Tags: api, dart, flutter

Let say everytime i want to send data to the database, how to make it look likes the page is loading?

```
  HashMap ApiParams1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
  ApiParams1.putIfAbsent("email", () => _email.text);
  ApiParams1.putIfAbsent("mobileno", () => _phonenumber.text);
  initApi("http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxx",
          ApiParams1)
      .PostApi()
      .then((response) {
    var jsondecode = json.decode(response);

    if (jsondecode["status"].toString() == "success") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: jsondecode["message"].toString(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      saveEmaildetails();
    } else if (jsondecode["status"].toString() != "success") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: jsondecode["message"],
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
  });
```

I expect that when i click a submit button, it will show some loading to notice the user that they are sending the data to the database. I want to make sure that the user does not multiple click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a statefull widget and create a boolean variable called isLoading that is initially false.

When the user presses the button, use setState to set it to true and when the request finishes, use setState again to set it to false.

Inside your button widget change onPressed to

```
onPressed: isLoading 
             ? null
             : _handlePress()
```